# How to add second button to Rails (simple) form_for in edit view to delete instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, routes

Environment is Ruby 2.0.0, Rails 4.1, Windows 8.1, Simple_Form, Devise, CanCan, Rolify.  The Devise "User" model was created as "Device".

I have a working simple_form_for form that allows me to perform updates on the device instance.  I am trying to add a second button to delete the instance instead.  It displays fine, and even the html input tag looks reasonable, but it seems to ignore any permutation given to the action and method variables and always go to devices#update.

Is it possible to do this within the edit view form?  The alternative, I guess, is to update routes.rb to go to devices#delegate and determine there whether to transfer control to the update or destroy method.  I should probably just do that, but it seems like this option should work especially given that the input tag is being formatted reasonably.  It just seems to be ignored.

I've tried many variations of the action/method combinations.  As I said, the input tag is formatted as I would expect but is just ignored.  That is frustrating.  I'd rather it throw an exception than just ignore me...

The form code is as follows:

```
<%= simple_form_for @device,
                    defaults: {label: false},
                    html: {class: 'form-vertical'},
                    wrapper: :vertical_form,
                    wrapper_mappings: {
                            check_boxes: :vertical_radio_and_checkboxes,
                            radio_buttons: :vertical_radio_and_checkboxes,
                            file: :vertical_file_input,
                            boolean: :vertical_boolean
                    } do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name, disabled: true, label: "Device name is:", required: false %>
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:role_ids, Role.where(name: "admin"), :id, :name) do |b|
      b.label(:"data-value" => b.value) { b.check_box + " Administrator?" }
    end %>
    <%= f.input :chg_pwd, as: :boolean,
                checked_value: true, unchecked_value: false,
                inline_label: "Generate new password?" %>
    <%= f.button(:submit, {class: 'btn btn-primary'}) %>
    <%= f.button(:submit, {value: "Delete Device", class: 'btn btn-primary', action: '/devices', method: 'delete'}) %>
<% end %>
```

I'd provide the HTML input tag but, as I said, I've tried so many options and they seem to be formatted correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just adding a link to the form like the following instead of fighting with Simple Form...

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', device_path(@device), :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

This allows you to execute a DELETE request to your controller with the specified object without screwing around with Simple Form and the way it handles form posting.  I think this is a much more straight solution, and prevents you from doing a delegate method as you suggested.

The following shows how you would use javascript to change the method on a form and then submit it.  This code assumes your delete button is a button tag with no type set.

```
$("form button.delete-btn").on("click", function(e){
  $(this).parent().attr("method","delete").submit();
});
```

Note: You may also need to change the action depending on how you have our routes setup.  I didn't test this code so it may not be the exact solution.

Comment: I certainly considered it and, if this were a one-off, I'd probably do that.  However, this is the first of several to many I expect to implement in this application as well as others, I'd do that.  But, if I do, then I have to format it specifically and carry other format changes through any time the occur.  I'd rather fix this once, if possible, and not re-address it over and over.  Thanks.

Comment: Based on your example above you would still need to re address it over and over.  You could try using javascript and use a onSubmit event to change the method of the form when the button is clicked and have the listener apply to all the forms you want.